# Check URL of every downloaded file and edit each one individually WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, download

I would like to create an if function that applies to all the files a customer purchases from a variation. If the file name contains a particular word I would like something to happen to that file and if it doesn't contain that word then I want something else to happen to the file.

This code works on the product level but doesn't apply to every individual file that a customer would download in a variation. It takes the information from the first downloadable file and applies it to all the files. How can I get the if function to run on every individual file and not just the first one?

```
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

    if ( $product->is_downloadable() ) {
        foreach( $product->get_downloads() as $key_download_id => $download ) {
        $download_link = $download->get_file(); // File Url
     }   
        
            if (strpos($download_link, "test") !== false) {
            (do something)  
            } 
        
        else {
            (do something different)
            } 
    }
    
    else {return $input;
    }
```